# How to display in-text citations in the `Author (Year)` format in ConTeXt?

Tags: bibtex, context, apa-style, context-mkiv

When writing in APA, one can write in-text in one of two ways:

```
(Willows, Q. A. & White, P., 1995)
```

Or, if the author's name is mentioned within the text, using this syntax:

```
Willows, Q. A. & White, P. (1995)
```

In ConTeXt, the command `\cite[Willows1995]`, where `Willow1995` is the BibTeX key, only outputs the in-text citation in the format shown in the first example. What command can I use in ConTeXt to display the author's name and date, but with only the date in parenthesis, as shown in the second example?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code.

Comment: Try: `\cite[alternative=authoryear][Willows1995]`

Comment: Village does the above work? if it doesn't, could you rewrite your question and add an MWE?

Comment: Yes, it works. I thought I left a comment, but maybe it didn't get posted.

Comment: Excellent! I'm kind of wary with your questions... since a deeper problem usually lies underneath it :), and I wasn't even sure the comment was the solution. @DG' could you write an answer so the question doesn't appear as unanswered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cite format you are looking for ist called `authoryear`. You can set it as an option:

```
\cite[alternative=authoryear][Willows1995]
```

Or you can set it as the default style for `\cite` using the `refcommand`-option:

```
\setuppublications
    [refcommand=authoryear]
```