# Where to find a comprehensive overview of the features of the ConTeXt cite command?

Tags: bibtex, context, apa-style, context-mkiv

I need to use the `\cite` command in ConTeXt very often for in-text citations in APA format, in a wide range of forms, e.g.:

1. (Author, YYYY)
2. Author (YYYY)
3. (Author, YYYY, p. n)
4. Author (YYYY, p. n)
5. (Author, YYYY, p. n; Author, YYYY, p. n) % two or more citations together
6. Title % title mentioned alone
7. Year % year mentioned alone
8. Author's (YYYY) % with possession
9. (p. n) % page number cited alone
10. p. n % page number cited alone

Rather than posting a new question each time I encounter a new form which I need to cite (e.g. [How to display in-text citations in the `Author (Year)` format in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210911/how-to-display-in-text-citations-in-the-author-year-format-in-context) and [How to add page numbers to APA citations in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73131/how-to-add-page-numbers-to-apa-citations-in-context) [How to add an APA-style citation with no author in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102846/how-to-add-an-apa-style-citation-with-no-author-in-context)), I wonder if there is some reference listing all of the available options in the `\cite` command?

I can find nothing in the [ConTeXt manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/cont-enp.pdf) and nothing in [ConTeXt Garden's entry on cite](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/cite) and related entries on [bibliographies](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Bibliography).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Documentation:**

You can find the documentation for bibliographies here: [bibmod-doc](http://modules.contextgarden.net/dl/bibmod-doc/doc/context/bib/bibmod-doc.pdf)

A new implementation is currently in beta. You can find the documentation for it here:

- [mkiv-publications](https://github.com/mojca/context/blob/master/doc/context/manuals/allkind/mkiv-publications.pdf)
- [From BibTeX to ConTeXt MKVI](http://meeting.contextgarden.net/2014/talks/2014-09-09-alan-bibtex/From_BibTeX_to_ConTeXt_MKVI.pdf)

**Some examples:**

These citation styles seem to work out of the box:

- (Author, YYYY)

  ```
  \cite[alternative=authoryears][author2001]
  ```
- Author (YYYY)

  ```
  \cite[alternative=authoryear][author2001]
  ```
- (Author, YYYY, p. n)

  ```
  \cite[alternative=authoryears,extras={, p.~n}][author2001]
  ```
- (Author, YYYY, p. n; Author, YYYY, p. n)

  ```
  (\cite[alternative=authoryears,left={},right={},extras={, p.~n}][author2001]; \cite[alternative=authoryears,left={},right={},extras={, p.~n}][buthor2001])
  ```

  *This is very clumsy*
- Author (YYYY, p. n)

  ```
  \cite[alternative=authoryear,extras={, p.~n}][author2001]
  ```
- Year

  ```
  \cite[year,left={},right={}][author2001]
  ```
- Author's (YYYY)

  ```
  \cite[alternative=author,left={},right={}][author2001]'s \cite[year][author2001]
  ```

  *This is not very elegant*

**Snippets:**

To make citing more comfortable, it would be useful to define wrappers:

```
\def\citet{\dosingleempty\doCiteT}
\def\doCiteT[#1]#2{%
  \iffirstargument
    \cite[alternative=authoryear,extras={, #1}][#2]%
  \else
    \cite[alternative=authoryear][#2]%
  \fi
}

\def\citep{\dosingleempty\doCiteP}
\def\doCiteP[#1]#2{%
  \iffirstargument
    \cite[alternative=authoryears,extras={, #1}][#2]%
  \else
    \cite[alternative=authoryears][#2]%
  \fi
}

\define[1]\citeyear{\cite[alternative=year,left={},right={}][#1]}
\define[1]\citeauthor{\cite[alternative=author,left={},right={}][#1]}
```

Now you can use:

- `\citet{author2001}`
- `\citep{author2001}`
- `\citet[p. n]{author2001}`
- `\citep[p. n]{author2001}`
- `\citeyear{author2001}`
- `\citeauthor{author2001}`